# How to call httpLoggingInterceptor inside request.newBuilder()

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, response

As I researched and found that ,  .**client(OkHttptvariableName)**
 is used inside builder inorder to print the api response into logcat.
But in my case, I cannot call the .client inbuild method with **request.newBuilder**.
Following is my code snippets.
Please help me.

```
 val httpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        httpLoggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
        val okHttpClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor).build()


when {
            UserInfo.loginStatus -> {
                request = request.newBuilder()
                    .header("Authorization", UserInfo.token)
                    .build()
            }
            else -> {
                request = request.newBuilder()

                    .build()
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is your expected behaviour

Comment: @NehaRathore ,I want to print the api response in Logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this example:

```
        val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY)
            httpClient.addInterceptor(logging)
        }

        Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build()
    }
```

for more info see: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-enable-logging-for-development-builds-only